# Function that removes all characters in the first string from the second string

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to write a function that removes all characters in the first string from the second string. I need to use recursion and another helper function that removes that removes all occurrences of a
character from a string. I couldn't add the recursive part.

rmCharsRec is the function that I am trying to write and rmChar is the other function.

```
rmCharsRec :: String -> String -> String
rmCharsRec [] ys = ys
rmCharsRec (x:xs) [] = []
rmCharsRec (x:xs) ys = rmChar x ys 

rmChar :: Char -> String -> String
rmChar c xs = filter ( /= c) xs

rmCharsRec ['a'..'l'] "football"
```

I am expecting the output "oot", but I am getting "footbll".

Comment: `rmChar` will only remove *one* sort of characters, but you need to recurse on the rest of the characters to remove.

Answer (score 4):

You say you need to use recursion, but nowhere do you have a function calling itself. In particular, when you have `x:xs`, don't you think you should care about `xs` at some point?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your third clause, you only remove the character `x` from the string. Indeed:

```
rmCharsRec :: String -> String -> String
rmCharsRec [] ys = ys
rmCharsRec (x:xs) [] = []
rmCharsRec (x:xs) ys = rmChar x ys
```

After you removed that character, you will still need to remove the other characters in the rest of the list `xs`.

You thus should recurse here, like:

```
rmCharsRec :: String -> String -> String
rmCharsRec [] ys = ys
rmCharsRec (x:xs) [] = []
rmCharsRec (x:xs) ys = rmCharsRec … (rmChar x ys)
```

with `…` the part you still need to fill in.